# Problem with MINUS and sub queries with ORDER BYs

Tags: oracle

```
select salary 
from (
        (select salary  
         from   employees 
         where rownum<=10 
         order by salary desc)
         minus
        (select salary 
         from   employees 
         where rownum<=4 
         order by salary desc)
      );
```

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: It throws ORA-00907, because of `order by` in subqueries. The simplest [solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8ad04efdc9c7b73c6bde9a5e5a02ff1f) is row_number(), but it's not clear if OP wants to do with distinct values, and `minus` removes them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `ORDER BY` there.

Try this instead:

```
select salary from (
    select salary, row_number() over ( order by salary desc ) rn
     from   employees )
where rn between 5 and 10;
```

On Oracle 12c or later, you can also do this:

```
select salary from employees
order by salary desc
offset 4 rows fetch next 6 rows only;
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got several issues in what you've written. The immediate problem is that you'll get an error from having an `order by` in the first branch of your union, but just removing that won't help you much.

You're making a (fairly common) mistake with ordering and `rownum`; looking just at the first subquery you have:

```
select salary  
from   employees 
where rownum<=10 
order by salary desc
```

The `rownum` filter will be applied *before* the order-by, so what this will actually produce is 10 indeterminate rows from the table, which are then ordered. If I run that I get:

```
    SALARY
----------
     24000
     13000
     12000
     10000
      8300
      6500
      6000
      4400
      2600
      2600
```

but you'll see different values, even from the same sample schema. If you look at the whole table you'll see higher values than those; and even running the second query will show something isn't as you expect - for me that gets:

```
    SALARY
----------
     13000
      4400
      2600
      2600
```

which are *not* the first four rows from the previous query. (Again, you'll see different results, but hopefully the same effect; if not, look at the whole table ordered by salary.)

You need to order the whole table - in a subquery - and then filter:

```
select salary 
from (
  select salary  
  from employees 
  order by salary desc
)
where rownum<=10
```

which gives a much more sensible - and consistent - result. You can then minus the two queries:

```
select salary 
from (
  select salary  
  from employees 
  order by salary desc
)
where rownum<=10
minus
select salary 
from (
  select salary 
  from employees 
  order by salary desc
)
where rownum<=4
order by salary desc;

    SALARY
----------
     13500
     13000
     12000
     11500
```

You may be expecting to see six values there, but there are three employees with a salary of 12000, and `minus` eliminates duplicates so that is only reported once. @Matthew's approach (or @Jeff's!) will give you all six, including duplicates, if that is what you want. It also stops you having to hit the table multiple times.

A further problem is with ties - if the 4th highest was the same as the 5th highest, what would you expect to happen? Using `minus` would exclude that value; @Matthew's approach would preserve it.

You need to define what you actually want to get - the 5th to 10th highest salary values? The salaries of the 5th to 10th highest-paid people (a subtle but important difference)? Do you really only want the numbers, or who those employees are - in which case how you deal with ties is even more important? Etc. Once you know what you actually need to find you can decide the best way to get that result.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to order rows in two sets that are subsequently operated upon because sets don't have order. If you need a solution that can execute on older versions and you want to return the bottom 6 ranked out of the top 10 ranked, then this will work. If you can use newer features, then you may want to because it's possible they'll require fewer machine instruction executions.

After making the obvious changes that escaped me in my haste...

```
select salary
from (
      select rownum rn, salary
      from (
            select salary
            from   employees
            order by salary desc
           )
      )
where rn between 5 and 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `rownum` is evaluated _before_ the `ORDER BY`.  So that query is not going to give the 5th through 10th highest salaries (except by luck).

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Agreed.